# quickfixj version2.3.1 , initiator can not get history message

Tags: quickfixj

quickfixj version：2.3.1,

The problem I have now is initiator Can not get history message。  The news is always up to date
If you know, please help me.

I use acceptor send  1，2，3，4，5，6，7，8，9，10，11，......

Bug I start initiator  I can only accept 9，10，11

miss 1，2，3....8

acceptor：config

```
# default settings for sessions
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=acceptor
ReconnectInterval=15
SenderCompID=QUICKFIX_ACCEPTOR
TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai
MaxLatency=3600
# log
FileStorePath=quickfixj/acceptor/store
FileLogPath=quickfixj/acceptor/log

SocketAcceptAddress=127.0.0.1
SocketAcceptPort=9823
# session definition
[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=INITIATOR_TEST
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=180

DataDictionary=FIX50SP2.modified.xml
UseDataDictionary=N
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2

[DEFAULT]
SocketReuseAddress=Y
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnLogout=N
ResetOnDisconnect=N
ResetOnError=N
DisconnectOnError=N
ContinueInitializationOnError=N
```

initiator config:

```
# default settings for sessions
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=15
SenderCompID=INITIATOR_TEST
TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai
MaxLatency=3600
# log
FileStorePath=quickfixj/initiator/store
FileLogPath=quickfixj/initiator/log
FileLogPath=quickfixj/initiator/log


# session definition
[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=QUICKFIX_ACCEPTOR
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=180
SocketConnectPort=9823
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
DataDictionary=FIX50SP2.modified.xml
UseDataDictionary=N
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2

[DEFAULT]
SocketReuseAddress=Y
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnLogout=N
ResetOnDisconnect=N
ResetOnError=N
DisconnectOnError=N
ContinueInitializationOnError=N
```

Comment: Can you show the messages that you sent? Maybe messages 1 through 8 were admin messages? These are not resent (except Reject message)

Comment: 8=FIXT.1.19=13935=QUOTE34=149=QUICKFIX_ACCEPTOR52=20240313-11:00:24.48956=INITIATOR_WANGJIN10000=hello:110001=time:19:00:24.48910=213

Comment: parsed message: pos=153,lim=153,rem=0,offset=153,state=4 8=FIXT.1.19=12935=434=143=Y49=QUICKFIX_ACCEPTOR52=20240313-11:00:36.17156=INITIATOR_TEST122=20240313-11:00:36.17136=6123=Y10=146

Comment: origin fixmessage:    8=FIXT.1.19=13935=QUOTE34=149=QUICKFIX_ACCEPTOR52=20240313-12:01:05.41656=INITIATOR_TEST10000=你好世界:110001=time:20:01:05.41610=186



please help me。    I invoke  [quickfix.Session#resendMessages]     invoke state.get(beginSeqNo, endSeqNo, messages) .    but intercept  10=186.

Comment: Apart from that, you shouldn't invoke these methods on your own. QFJ takes care of the session logic.

Comment: by changing line 366 from final int size = message.length(); to final int size = message.getBytes(CharsetSupport.getCharset()).length; solve this problem

https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues/650

Comment: I've verified it
this is bug.

Comment: I know, I proposed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

by changing line 366
from
final int size = message.length();
to
final int size = message.getBytes(CharsetSupport.getCharset()).length;
solve this problem

https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues/650

Comment: Wow, was not expecting that solution. You should have posted the problematic message right in your question. Otherwise it is just guesswork.